# Why does Anaconda Navigator (Windows) show a different version of Tensorflow than the command line?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I recently created a new Anaconda (Windows) environment in order to move from tensorflow 1.2 to tensorflow 2.0. My base environment is 1.2, and I created `tensorflow-20` in order to install the new version. I did the install from the anaconda command line within the `(tensorflow-20)` environment. But now everything is messed up.

Now, in Anaconda Navigator, it still shows Tensorflow 1.2.1 as the installed version for `base`. But in the `(base)` environment from the Anaconda command line, it shows the version as 2.0.0. Furthermore, in Anaconda Navigator, `tensorflow-20` shows no installed packages, including python even.

I feel like I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something here. Can anyone provide some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

How did you install tensorflow 2.0 in the new conda env?

- IF with pip, run 'where pip' see if you are using the pip installed
  in the base env. You can run 'conda create -n tensorflow-20 pip' to get a pip installed in the new env. Then activate tensorflow-20 and install tensorflow 2.0 with pip.
- IF with conda, run 'where conda' to check the same thing.

Comment: `where pip` shows me `C:\Users\[username]\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe`. Is that the base environment?

Comment: @tobogranyte yes, I think so, it should be some thing as this with "envs\{your env name}" in the path:
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf2\Scripts\pip.exe

Comment: you can create conda env with some command like "conda create -n tensorflow-20 pip" to get pip installed for the new conda env directly and then use pip to install tensorflow 2.0

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:**
If you install Anaconda on your local machine, it makes sense to install it as Admin. However, if this is not possible, e.g. on an enterprise-managed computer, you must carefully check to use only folders where your user has write permission.

**Contribution:**
After having experienced a cracked-up package management, I read deeper into that topic. Best Practise: Always try to install everything via conda / Anaconda and best possibly from their central repositories.
If you have a special package, which is e.g. built by local software developers and not published, you can install it from the .tar archive. At that point, I am referring to following documentation: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/